# How correctly to filter entries by date range in Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to filter entries for the period in `Elasticsearch`. I use Elasticsearch `version 6.4.1`.

I use such **URL**:

```
http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?q=stamper:[2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z+TO+2018-10-07T23:59:59.999Z]&q=city=London
```

In result I see all entries about London city, but date range filter don't work. How to fix it?

I check the format of `stamper` field in Kibana. It show me this:

```
Type: date
Format: Date
```

`Result` example:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "_index": "youtube",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "K6OKZ2YBmp2VWXSDhFPc",
        "_score": 0.9570947,
        "_source": {
            "avg": 6258.5,
            "price": "2259",
            "region": "England",
            "@version": "1",
            "description_id": "7406",
            "stamper": "2018-09-28T08:00:00.000Z",,
            "area": "London",
            "datefor": "2018-09-28",
            "@timestamp": "2018-10-12T09:10:23.103Z",
            "city": "London",
        }
    },
    [***]
]
```

I notice that if we remove `&q=city=London` from URL it return all entries for period of all cities. It seems like my URL is not correct. How to make correct URL which hasm ultiple parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The correct url to search this is:

```
http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?q=stamper:[2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z+TO+2018-10-07T23:59:59.999Z] AND city:London
```

When encoded it will be like:

```
http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?q=stamper:[2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z+TO+2018-10-07T23:59:59.999Z]%20AND%20city:London
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason of the problem. It was incorrect URL.

If you want to use `multiple parameters` in your `URL` use:

```
http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?q=stamper:[2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z+TO+2018-10-07T23:59:59.999Z]%20AND%20city:London
```

Comment: Still not correct, the end should be `city:London` (with `:` not `=`)